# Changing PowerPoint Text Frame Size

Tags: python, text, automation, powerpoint, python-pptx

I'm trying to change the size of a `text_frame` to match the size of the PowerPoint slide I'm automating the creation of. I've found that I can change the slide width and slide height via...

```
prs=Presentation()
prs.slide_width = Inches(16)
prs.slide_height = Inches(9)
```

And title shape via...

```
title_shape = shapes.title
title_shape.width = Inches(16)
title_shape.height = Inches(2)
```

but this method doesn't have any effect on the text_frame using the following code...

```
        slide = prs.slides.add_slide(bullet_slide_layout)
        shapes = slide.shapes
        title_shape = shapes.title
        title_shape.width = Inches(16)
        title_shape.height = Inches(2)
        body_shape = shapes.placeholders[1]
        title_shape.text = project['name']
        tf = body_shape.text_frame
        tf.text = ""
        tf.width = Inches(16)
        tf.height = Inches(9)
```

I thought the `tf.width` and `tf.height` would do the trick, but it's not working for me. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by manipulating the text-frame size? The "size" of the text-frame is neither discoverable nor directly settable, so I don't think that approach is going to work. But if you help us understand the outcome you're looking for maybe we can help you accomplish it.

Comment: @Scanny I am automating the creation of slides that are 16 inch wide and 9 inches height. The text-frame that is input into those dimensions just doesn't fit correctly leading to manual fixing I don't want the user to have to do

Comment: @Bob It's a good idea to use PowerPoint's own terminology (and not use PowerPoint terms to mean other things) when asking questions. I'm guessing you simply want to change the size of the body text *placeholder* or some other *text shape*.  TextFrame is a different thing.  Before adding text to the body text placeholder, use body_shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = ppAutoSizeNone

Answer (score 1):

The things on a PowerPoint slide that have size are *shapes*. The title-placeholder is a shape (basically a *textbox* shape) and so is the body placeholder.

So to change its size you assign to the shape's width and height properties:

```
body_shape = shapes.placeholders[1]
body_shape.width = Inches(16)
body_shape.height = Inches(9)
```

Certain shapes (the geometric ones called *autoshapes*) can contain text. Other shapes like picture shapes can't. When a shape can contain text, the shape has a `.text_frame` property that is the "container" of the text for the shape and controls certain aspects of how it is formatted, like whether it wraps etc.

But the text-frame does not have a size, per se; how big the text-frame appears is determined by the size of the shape it belongs to and to a certain degree the wrap settings and how much text is in it.

Comment: If a shape has a text frame, its .HasTextFrame property will be True. Otherwise, False. And if that returns True, you can use the shape's .TextFrame.HasText property (True if the text frame contains text, False otherwise).

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Just to note that while that's true in the Microsoft API, which `python-pptx` generally tries to stay consistent with, there is no `.has_text` property on a `TextFrame` object in `python-pptx`. I suppose we just figured you could test directly on the `.text` property, in Python something like: `if text_frame.text:  # do text things`. https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#textframe-objects

Comment: From reading other Python vs PPT posts hereabouts, I got the idea that the entire PPT object model isn't yet available.  It might be necessary to trap any errors in the line of code you mention or not, depending on how python-pptx handles textless textframes. Or so I'd guess, but you're well aware of that, I'd also guess. ;-)

Comment: @SteveRindsberg The XML Schema for a textframe (`<p:txBody>` element) requires that it contain at least one paragraph. That paragraph can have zero runs (which is what a newly created shape gets), but we still interpret `text_frame.text` in that case to be the empty string. So `text_frame.text` is always a `str` value. That simplifies the interface and I haven't yet heard of a compelling use case where someone would want to distinguish. They could of course, using something like `len(list(r for p in text_frame.paragraphs for r in p.runs)) == 0`. But no takers on that yet as far as I know :)

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me. I suspect that the .HasText property is there because of some historical bugs/oddities (this is going WAY back, mind) in which PPT made a distinction between a shape that had a textframe containing text and a shape with no text, which PPT would treat as though there were no textframe. There seems to be no difference now between testing for .HasText and querying the length of text in the textframe, where 0 length = a false for .HasText.  Speaking from VBA's view of things here.